# How to find substring in file?

Tags: python

How to find string in binary file using only read(1) ?
For example I want to found position of string 'abst' in file ( without load to memory ) ?
It's work but very primitive:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
f = open("/tmp/rr", "rb")
f.seek(0)

cont = 1
while(cont):
    a1 = f.read(1)
    if a1 == 'a':
        a2 = f.read(1)
        if a2 == 'b':
            a3 = f.read(1)
            if a3 == 's':
                a4 = f.read(1)
                if a4 == 't':
                    found = True
                    cont = 0
```

Comment: What if the file contains `aabst`?

Comment: Why do you want to use only `read(1)`? Is this a homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a substring by using the strings find-method.

```
content = file.read()
name = 'abst'
if name in content:
    slice = content.find(name)
    slice = slice, slice + len(name)
```

*The `read(1)`-method is absolutely senseless.* #see edit

**Edit**: more effiecient for the memory

```
def find(file, name):
    length = len(name)
    part = file.read(length)
    i = 0
    while True:
        if part == name:
            break
        char = file.read(1)
        if not char:
            return
        part = part[1:] + char
        i += 1
    return i, i + length, part
```

I see, using `read(1)` isn't that senseless.

Comment: This approach requires memory in the amount of the file, which is totally unnecessary just for searching.

Comment: @philhag: doesn't the `mmap` approach also require storing the file in memory?

Answer (score 4):

Use [mmap](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html) to search the file with constant memory requirements:

```
import mmap
with open('/tmp/rr', 'rb') as f:
  m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, mmap.MAP_PRIVATE, mmap.PROT_READ)
  position = m.index('abst')
```

Comment: Updated with `position` instead of `found`. The result will be -1 if the string isn't found.

Answer (score 2):

Will this work for you?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

string = "abst"
f = open("/tmp/rr", "rb")
f.seek(0)

cont = 1
idx = 0
while True:
    c = f.read(1)
    if c == '':
        break
    if c == string[idx]:
        idx += 1
    elif c == string[0]:
        idx = 1
    else:
        idx = 0
    if idx == len(string):
        print "Found"
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file is mostly filled with 'a's, or whatever character corresponds to the first character in the string you're searching for, this algo will suck big time, otherwise works pretty well.

```
check = 'abst'
col=1
row=1
location = (-1, -1)

with open("/tmp/rr", 'rb') as p:
    ch = p.read(1)
    while(ch != ""):
        if ch == check[0]:
            st = p.read(len(check)-1)
            if ch+st == check:
                location = (row, col)
                break
            else:
                p.seek(-len(check)+1, 1)

        ch = p.read(1)
        col+=1

        if ch == '\n':
            col=0
            row+=1

print("loc: {}, {}".format(*location))
```